# Ansible: Changing permissions of files but not of directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to set the permissions of the files under a directory but I don't want to change the permission of the directory.

I tried this:

```
- name: chmod 444
  file: /dir recurse=yes state=directory owner=abc group=abc mode=0444
```

But it will modify the directory permission also. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in one task.

You need first to find files and then execute the `file` module with the appropriate settings against the list.

```
- find:
    path: /dir
    file_type: file
    recurse: yes
  register: find_result

- file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    owner: abc
    group: abc
    mode: 0444
  with_items: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Comment: Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

in one task using shell:

```
- shell: "find . -type f -exec chmod 0444 {} \\;"
  args:
    chdir: /dir
```

Comment: This is not idempotent in the ansible way and always shows up as changed.